# Get the element below the ready-function code, in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example:

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    alert( $(this).getBelowElementToThisScript('form').id );
});
</script>
<form id="IamTheNext"></form>
<form id="Iamnot"></form>
```

This code should show this message: IamTheNext

In addition, the solution needs to work with this example too:

```
<script src="getbelowelement.js"></script>
<form id="IamTheNext"></form>
<form id="Iamnot"></form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var form = $('script[src="getbelowelement.js"]').next();
```

But I would suggest using the forms id:

```
var form = $('#IamTheNext');
```

Comment: Not that, I like something like this: $(this).closest( 'script' ).next('form').id

Comment: @Cristian: note that what you like is not always the best solution

Answer (score 1):

You could also try giving the script tag an id.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of approach is dangerous; script should never depend that much on where it is in the page.

That said, the following works in Firefox and Chrome and ***should*** work in the major browsers (use at your own risk).

[**See it in action at jsBin.**](http://jsbin.com/otohuy/2)  Both `<script> ...` and `<script src="...">` approaches are shown in the same page.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    invocationsOfThis   = (typeof invocationsOfThis == 'number') ? invocationsOfThis + 1 : 1;
    var scriptTags      = document.getElementsByTagName ('script');
    var thisScriptTag   = null;

    //--- Search scripts for scripts of this type.
    for (var foundCnt = 0, J = 0, L = scriptTags.length;  J < L;  ++J)
    {
        /*--- Since the script can be either inline or included, search
            both the script text and the script src link for our unique
            identifier.
        */
        var thisTag     = scriptTags[J];
        var scriptCode  = thisTag.innerText || thisTag.textContent;
        var scriptSrc   = thisTag.src;

        //--- IMPORTANT, change pastebin.com to the filename that you use.
        if (/invocationsOfThis/i.test (scriptCode)  ||  /pastebin.com/i.test (scriptSrc))
        {
            //--- Found a copy of this script; is it the right one, based on invocation cnt?
            foundCnt++;
            if (foundCnt == invocationsOfThis) {
                thisScriptTag = thisTag;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (thisScriptTag) {
        //--- Get the target node.
        var nextForm        = $(thisScriptTag).next ('form');
        var nextFormId      = nextForm.attr ('id');

        //--- Act on the target node.  Here we notify the user
        nextForm.text ('This is form: "' + nextFormId + '".');
    }
} );
```